# How to group items by location and summing their quantity?

Tags: c#

Everything shown below is purely pseudo-code to illustrate my problem.

My code has the following data structures:

```
// Used to define the ORDERS a customer has placed
List<Orders> myOrders;
Orders
{
  String name
  double quantity
  String location   // there are only 2 possible locations
}

// Used to define the ITEMS we have available
Item
{
  String name
  List<Parts> parts
}

// Used to define the PARTS to make an ITEM
Parts
{
  String name
  double quantity
}
```

The general breakdown seems nice and clear, but the customer requirements is where I am having issues and I am not sure how to best resolve the problem... (NOTE - I know using NAME and not an ID is bad to correlate - but this is a legacy system).

What I need to generate is the following:
- list of all PARTS by item needed from each LOCATION (only two possible) and the actual quantity defined by the orders
- display this on the screen to be printed
!! obviously you can have multiple order for the same parts at the same location and they should be added together to get a total.

So what I need to do:
- take each order and find the item
- take each item and find the parts
- for each part define its location (from order) and multiply by quantity (from order) and that is the # of parts for this location

The end result should be something like this (table grid form headers)

```
    Item    Part    QuantityLocation1   QuantityLocation2
    itm1      A         1                    0
              B         4                    2
    itm2      C         0                    5
```

The issue being that obvious the PART class has no such concept as LOCATION...

Anyone have any suggestions?
The only solution I can see right now seems horrible ... create a new class (like PartswithLocation), add the location to it, and then recreate all the ITEM objects (that already exist) with this PartsWithLocation, then I can do some magic ORDER by ORDER to find the parts and based on Location and multiply in the quantity. The end result is a new List that I can then display in a grid or something (WPF)... But man this sounds ugly ...

This is purely a DESIGN related question, I am not looking for source code just some ideas on how to better resolve my issue.
Thank you for your time and help,

Comment: Is the `name` field in `Orders` the same as the `name` field in `Item`?

Comment: Yes, Order.name and Item.name are equal

Comment: Does `Parts.name` also correspond to `Orders`?  Otherwise, you can't break it down by Location at all, because you aren't tracking it.  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No Parts.Name the name of the PART in question (not the same), look at the table example I provided. Customer will order 5x itm1 (item #1). Order.Name = itm1 and if you look in the list of ITEMS there is one Item.name = itm1. So you found the ITEM for that order. That item has a list of PARTS that make it and each part has a name (A, B, C, etc...)

Comment: But if your system doesn't know how many of part A is in a given location, then there's no way to get that information.

Comment: The LOCATION is defined by the ORDER, it is not where to get it but where it is going

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.  Your example was confusing me, since the ratio of A:B in Location 1 was different from the ratio in Location 2.  Let me see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need any more than what you have now, if you manipulate your data on the fly correctly.

In pseudocode, here's what you need to do:

```
foreach(order in orders)
{
   order.partlist = GetItem(order.name).parts; // partlist is a list of Part objects, not stored anywhere.
}
foreach(location in locations)
{
   foreach(order in GetOrdersAtLocation(location))
   {
      foreach(part in order.parts)
      {
         location.partlist += { part.name, part.quantity * order.quantity }; // partlist is a list of parts and quantities, to be displayed.
      }
   }
 }
```

I'd do this in LINQ, but since you asked for a design answer rather than code, this is more-or-less what it would unwrap to.

Comment: You are missing Item.Name in all this ... but generally this is what I thought .... thanks ...

Comment: @JSchwartz - That's what `GetItem()` does.  It returns an `Item` based on the name that's passed in.

Comment: I see what you mean, but what do we actually diplay to the user in this case? Where is the result stored?

Comment: @JSchwartz - In `location.partlist`.  That could represent a property on the `location` object, a `Dictionary<Location, List<Part>>`, the actual `SELECT` statement, `yield return`, `Console.WriteLine()`, etc...  It's an implementation detail.